# Send and receive files between two servers

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, file

I need a method to send (files or string) between php server and nodejs server.

I would like to have an easy solution ; I don't want to use cURL, or a third server to communicate between Apache and Node servers. What I want is to be able to catch events from node in simple Javascript, client-side.

I didn't find any answers that where complete, most of the time client-side was running by the node server and so not applicable in my case. So I crawled all the possible topics, and finally find my answer ; I'll try to share this, and to have a point where it's all clear.

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear. Please, be more specific, give exemple... Read [How to Ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post.

PHP and Node JS have APIs to get or send data through network. If you have difficulties to understand the API documentation you need to precise what you don't understand.

Comment: Can you give me information or documents about this APIs? Can I use SocketIO for this?

Comment: No you can't use SocketIO with PHP. But for file transfert HTTP is enough. Please give me more details. You need to transfert files from PHP to Node or from Node to PHP ? Maybe both ? Witch side initiate the transfert. Edit your question to give the details. You have say you don't want to use cUrl, but it's the standard way if you need to make and HTTP request with PHP. http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php | https://nodejs.org/api/http.html